# Disable MySQL auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password plugin

Tags: php, mysql, plugins

Apologies if this is rookie question, but I feel like I've tried everything.  In my phpinfo.php file, I'm showing that the plugin auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password is enabled under mysqlnd.

[image]

Our security group is telling me that I need to disable it.  I found this link: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cleartext-pluggable-authentication.html) and tried to SET the LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN environment variable to 0 in the command line with the following syntax:

```
mysql> SET LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=0;
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error message:

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'
```

Why would I get that error message if it's showing up as enabled in the phpinfo.php file?

I can't remember ever enabling this plugin to begin with.  Anyone dealt with this problem before?

Thank you!

Comment: Your link says **environment** variable, not MySQL variable. That's something you set at OS level. What's your operating system?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm running it out of a Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.  Do you know where I can change that environment variable at the OS level?

Comment: https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-set-environmental-variables-in-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: I added that as an environment variable, but to no avail.  :(

Comment: Does the variable show up in the *Apache Environment* section of `phpinfo()`'s output?

Comment: There's no Apache Environment section of the phpinfo output.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming Apache for no reason. Is there a section that displays environment variables? What does `var_dump($_ENV['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN']);` print?

Comment: I get an error message saying, "Notice: Undefined index: LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN".  It does appear to be set for the $_SERVER['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] variable because when I write this command $_SERVER['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'], I get "0".  So it seems to be set to 0.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with mysqlnd as to tell where exactly it grabs `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` from but your web server doesn't seem to be passing environment variables to PHP as environment variables.